# Signup not proceeding to Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

Once a user signs in to my app, I need to take them to a tab view controller so they can use the app to its fullest potential. I have tried to initiate the TabBarController in the buttons onClick function with no success.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KlikurHomeTabs") as! UITabBarController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) // this shows it modally
        } else if error!.code == 101 {
            var invalidLogin:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "The username password combo you have us does not match our records, please try again or reset your password.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
            invalidLogin.show()
        }
    }
```

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong? I have no clue and have been trying for a while now. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have a storyboard, why not simply link a segue from your view controller object and then just `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your login success handler

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line and also take out the storyboard line of code

```
       let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KlikurHomeTabs") as! UITabBarController
```

To

```
   let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("KlikurHomeTabs") 
            self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an elaboration on Paulw11's comment, but here is what I am doing.  I have a "splash" view controller that has 2 storyboard segues,  one to a signin/signup view controller, and one to my main tabview controller.  Inside viewDidAppear, I check the login status and then perform one of the two segues.  Here is an example of the code.

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if needsLogin {
      performSegueWithIdentifier("SignIn/SignUP", sender: self)
    } else {
      performSegueWithIdentifier("MainTabBar", sender: self)
    }

  }
```